# tasklist does not list all Modules in 64-systems

Tags: python, windows, winapi, dll, tasklist

I've got some problem. I'll tried to get all modules(dll files) for all processes on my machine. I tried to do this command in CMD:

```
tasklist /m
```

But it's a problem with 64-bit systems. If you`re running a 32-bit programm on 64-bit machine it does not list all modules, only

```
ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll, wow64cpu.dll
```

Then i tried to do this with Python script, using pywin32 (win32api).

This is code:

```
import win32security,win32file,win32api,ntsecuritycon,win32con,win32process

processes = win32process.EnumProcesses()

for pid in processes:
    dll_list = []
    try:
        if pid:
            print('pid:', pid)
            ph = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, False, pid)
            dll = win32process.EnumProcessModules(ph)
            for dll_name in dll:
                dll_name_norm = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(ph, dll_name)
                dll_list.append(dll_name_norm)

            print("dll_list: ", dll_list)
            print("--------------")
    except:
        print("Error")
        print("--------------")
```

But result is the same. =( 
Please, help me with this, how I can see all dll files, load by each process.

P.S. It can be only standart Windows tools like command line, tasklist (NOT ListDlls, Process Explorer or the same thing) or script in Python.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just shows processes with the same bittiness as Python. Instead, call [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `dwFilterFlag=LIST_MODULES_ALL`.

Your current code requires the `win32api` module, which only [recently added `EnumProcessModulesEx`](http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/feature-requests/100/), and which is not in the standard library. Here is a solution that uses only the standard library:

```python
from ctypes import byref, create_unicode_buffer, sizeof, WinDLL
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, HMODULE, MAX_PATH

Psapi = WinDLL('Psapi.dll')
Kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32.dll')

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010

LIST_MODULES_ALL = 0x03

def EnumProcesses():
    buf_count = 256
    while True:
        buf = (DWORD * buf_count)()
        buf_size = sizeof(buf)
        res_size = DWORD()
        if not Psapi.EnumProcesses(byref(buf), buf_size, byref(res_size)):
            raise OSError('EnumProcesses failed')
        if res_size.value >= buf_size:
            buf_count *= 2
            continue
        count = res_size.value // (buf_size // buf_count)
        return buf[:count]

def EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess):
    buf_count = 256
    while True:
        buf = (HMODULE * buf_count)()
        buf_size = sizeof(buf)
        needed = DWORD()
        if not Psapi.EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess, byref(buf), buf_size,
                                          byref(needed), LIST_MODULES_ALL):
            raise OSError('EnumProcessModulesEx failed')
        if buf_size < needed.value:
            buf_count = needed.value // (buf_size // buf_count)
            continue
        count = needed.value // (buf_size // buf_count)
        return map(HMODULE, buf[:count])

def GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hModule):
    buf = create_unicode_buffer(MAX_PATH)
    nSize = DWORD()
    if not Psapi.GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, hModule,
                                      byref(buf), byref(nSize)):
        raise OSError('GetModuleFileNameEx failed')
    return buf.value

def get_process_modules(pid):
    hProcess = Kernel32.OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
        False, pid)
    if not hProcess:
        raise OSError('Could not open PID %s' % pid)
    try:
        return [
            GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hModule)
            for hModule in EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess)]
    finally:
        Kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)

for pid in EnumProcesses():
    try:
        dll_list = get_process_modules(pid)
        print('dll_list: ', dll_list)
    except OSError as ose:
        print(str(ose))
    print('-' * 14)
```